# Disable http client caching angular 13

Tags: angular, spring

I have some kind of weird problem, or something that I don't understand. Well I have an application backend with spring and frontend with angular 13, of course there are some http calls to consume the spring api, sometimes we have some problems with the cache, the old requests persist even we change some or the entire http call params.
We have implement the [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) solution to control header cache, but unfortunately the problem persist. Often we deal with it by refreshing the page ctrl+f5. Is it related to other issues or browser kind !
Need your guidance, thank you
Example of what we implement to intercept HTTP requests and set the headers cache:

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpHeaders, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class CacheInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(req: HttpRequest, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent> {
        if (req.method === "yourRequestMethod") {
            const httpRequest = req.clone({
                headers: new HttpHeaders({
                    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
                    "Pragma": "no-cache",
                    "Expires": "Sat, 30 Mar 2024 00:00:00 GMT"
                })
            });
            return next.handle(httpRequest);
        }
        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

We hook it to the root component of the Angular app

```
..
providers: [
    {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: CacheInterceptor,
        multi: false
    }
...
```

Comment: Do you mean that no requests are sent to the backend?

Comment: @ZarghamKhan thank you for your response . Nope, but the old request persist even we do change some parameters, or like we still get the data from the old request response. For instance the old response fetch 200 rows, with the new one, we expect to get 300 rows, but we still get 200 !